ClientException with SocketException: How Do I Access My API
I am getting this error after I deployed my to my shared web host. Here is the error:
ClientException with SocketException: Failed host lookup 'mywebsite. com' (OS Error: No address associated with hostname, errno = 7, uri=https://mywebsite. com/login
How do I resolve this... The website is live and working

...yes, that's how URLs work

Yes for sure you can use any URL that is online. You just need to update the value of hostConnect and create a new build to test and deploy.
class API{
   static const hostConnect = "https://mywebsite/myappapi";
   static const uploadFolderURL = "$hostConnect/uploads/";
   static const loginAPIURL = "$hostConnect/apis/login";
   static const updateUserProfileUri = "$hostConnect/edit-profile";
   static const userProfileDataURL = "$hostConnect/profile-data";
}

